# Jquery Ajax request fails with no clear error

Tags: ajax, jquery

Just wanted to clarify upfront that I'm very new to jquery. 
I want to make an ajax call to retrieve some json data from an endpoint
but everything I tried fails (I get a status code of 0 and no response text).

This is the endpoint I am trying to retrieve data from:
`http://www.corpcomm.com/ccgwebapi/sample.ashx`

I am using `JQuery 1.9.0` and trying to load the `json` data when `document.ready`
gets called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
error: AjaxError
});

function AjaxError(x, e) {
if (x.status == 0) {
alert(x.status);
} else if (x.status == 404) {
alert('Requested URL not found.');
} else if (x.status == 500) {
alert('Internel Server Error.');
} else {
alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
}
}



$.get("http://www.corpcomm.com/ccgwebapi/sample.ashx",function () {
alert("success");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the json data, then you have to use `$.getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.corpcomm.com/ccgwebapi/sample.ashx', function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
     console.log(val);
   });
});
```

`Same origin policy` has to be considered for this.

Comment: I believe the cross domain call is a factor here but even after I took that into consideration I am still having trouble. Here is the updated code:

`var URL = "http://www.corpcomm.com/ccgwebapi/sample.ashx";

function alertResponse(data, status) {
  alert("data: " + data + ", status: " + status);
}

$.getJSON(URL + "&callback=?", alertResponse);`

Comment: Also tried this, again with no success:

`$.ajax({
                    url:"http://www.corpcomm.com/ccgwebapi/sample.ashx",
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success:function(json){
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSBIN and look at the console Im getting JSON back fine: http://jsbin.com/iwujew/1/edit

this the the response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "error": false
}
```

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: I don't get anything back (and no console input either).
By the way why did you use post?